# trigger a "switch" that has controls of which parts to display

Tags: html, django

```
<span id='question'>{{QuestionText}}</span>
<br>
<form action={{address}}>
{% for each in AnswerQuery %}
<span>{{each.answer}}</span><input type='radio' name="answer">
<span>Votes:{{each.answercount}}</span>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Hey, I am using django template for google app engine project. what is above is a snippet of my codes. But I am wondering if there is a way that I can choose to display the html partially. like if under some circumstances, I dont want the users to see the QuestionText,  so I just close it up somehow while still displaying the rest of it. I know I can render different templates which are modified accordingly,but would that be too trivial that I have to render a bunch of different templates.  Would be that nice if I can just change a part of the template and reuse it. I guess the magic is from the django part, the client side,but I dont know how. Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to hide the content and they show it with JavaScript (client-side) based on some user action, this will work:

```
<span id="question" style="display: none;">{{QuestionText}}</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // This requires jQuery
    $('document').ready(function(){
        if(some_foo_bar == true){
            $('#question').show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you want to just not show the portion of content at all (ie, don't even output it to the browser), this will work:

```
{% if some_variable_set_in_django_view_context %}
<span id='question'>{{QuestionText}}</span>
{% endif %}
<br>
<form action={{address}}>
{% for each in AnswerQuery %}
<span>{{each.answer}}</span><input type='radio' name="answer">
<span>Votes:{{each.answercount}}</span>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I need the second one since the factor that can decide which portion to be displayed is sent from the server. {% if some_variable_set_in_django_view_context %} but I dont quite understand this part, like how to trigger the if statement? like I pass some variables into the if? like what variables? Thank you so much

Comment: The same place where `QuestionText` is being set (in the view) is where you'll want to set `foo_variable`. When the page is being rendered, Django will look at the `{% if %}` statement and if `foo_variable` evaluates to `True` the code in between the `if` and the `endif` will be used (I say `foo_variable` because you can name it whatever you want).